# How to get track URIs from the Spotify API

Tags: swift, spotify

I am currently writing a program which utilizes the Spotify API

I have a program which is capable of playing a track if I have the track URI. My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out how to get the track URI by calling the Spotify API. I was trying to use the SPTRequest class as this was what was in a video which was linked from the Spotify API page, but this is a deprecated class and I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to navigate these classes. What would I do to get a Spotify track URI if for example I was searching by song name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Search endpoint!](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/)

It will return a track object, which contains the track uri.

Comment: Also do you have any good examples of swift programs which utilize the Spotify API? All of your website tutorials are in Objective C

Comment: We unfortunately don't have any Swift tutorials yet, but a developer in the community has made a tutorial that may be helpful: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/847